# Returning empty iterator in C++ hash table code

Tags: c++, hash, iterator, hashtable, isnullorempty

I'm following some handwritten notes on the implementation of a hash table with separate chaining. In particular I'm looking to this function:

```
list<ListCell>::iterator TablaHash::FoundOnList(int key, int table_row){
    for(list<ListCell>::iterator found= table[table_row].begin(); 
            found != table[table_row].end();found++){
        if((*found).Key() == key){
            return found;
        }
    }
    return Ø;
}
```

where the last symbol is the empty set. I understand I should return an "empty" iterator there but what should I do? Maybe return the end() iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, returning the `end()` iterator is the most natural thing in C++.

For instance, [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) returns the `end` iterator if it cannot find the item searched.

Comment: Could I use 0 instead? There is a function afterwards that returns  FoundOnList(key,table_row) != 0 to see if certain element exists on the table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no empty iterator concept in c++. You should return end() iterator. Even standard STL algoirthims do the same.